# Upload two images into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have successfully uploaded one image but having trouble with multiple images.
How do I upload a second image? Do I create a new field in the database and call it photo02 and then put another form input called photo2. How do I change the target to upload and move two files?

The form

```
Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" multiple>
Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" multiple>
```

The Code

```
$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES ('$pic' )") ; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['photo'] ['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 
require_once 'SimpleImage.php';
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($target);
$image->resize(50,50);
$image->save($target);
```

The Output

```
echo '<b> Picture 1: </b>','<img src="/upload/' . $row->photo . '" border=1>';
echo '<b> Picture 2: </b>','<img src="/upload/' . $row->photo . '" border=1>';
```

Comment: What is the structure of your `employees` table? Based on the code above we must assume it has one column which holds the image.

Comment: it has more columns, name, age, address, city.... but I only put one to make it simpler

Answer (score 0):

The drill is the same, you just have to put a multiple attribute:

```
 <input type="file" name="photo" multiple>
```

And then the $_FILES array will contain more pictures.

You can view it with print_r($_FILES);

Comment: Do I need to change the output?

Comment: What do you mean by "output"?

Answer (score 0):

Uses foreach over array $_FILES

```
if(isset($_FILES ['uploaded_files']))
{
     **foreach($_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'] as $key=>$value)**
     {
          if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'][$key]) && $_FILES[['uploaded_files']['error'][$key] == 0)
          {
                $filename = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'][$key];
                $filename = time().rand(0,999).$filename;

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'][$key], 'uploads/'. $filename))
                {
                      echo 'The file '. $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'][$key].' was uploaded successful';
                }
                else
                {
                      echo 'There was a problem uploading the picture.';
                } 
          }
          else
          {
            echo 'There is a problem with the uploading system.';
          }
     }
}

?>
```